# Show that the number 2.46^(1/64) is known within less than one unit in the place of its fifth significant digit

Tags: numerical-methods

This question (from Hildebrand's Introduction to Analysis) states:

> Show that the number $2.46^{\frac{1}{64}}$ is known within less than one unit in the place of its fifth significant digit if $2.46$ is known only to be corrected to three digits

What does the part

> one unit in the place of its fifth significant digit

mean? My understand was that this means that $\left|E(2.46^{\frac{1}{64}})\right| \leq 1 \times 10^{-5}$. My final answer was $\left|E(2.46^{\frac{1}{64}})\right| \leq 1.5878087... \times 10^{-5}$. So either my understanding of the question is off, or my answer is off.

My work:

Assume that $2.46$ is only known to be rounded correctly to three digits.
Then $E(2.45) \leq 5 \times 10 ^{-3}$ by (1.4.5).
Define $f(N) = N^{\frac{1}{64}}$.
Then $f'(N) = \frac{1}{64} N^{-\frac{63}{64}}$.
By (1.5.2),
\begin{align*}
  E(f(\overline{N})) &\leq \left| f'(\eta) \right|_{\text{max}} \left| E(\overline{N})\right|
  && \text{Where } \eta \text{ between } N - E(\overline{N}) \text{ and } N + E(\overline{N})\\
  E(f(2.46)) &\leq \left| \frac{1}{64} \eta ^{-\frac{63}{64}} \right|_{\text{max}} \cdot 2.46 \times 10^{-3}\\
  &\leq \left| \frac{1}{64} (2.46 - 5 \times 10^{-3}) \right| \cdot 2.46 \times 10^{-3}\\
  &\leq 1.5878087... \times 10^{-5}
\end{align*}

Where

> $E$ = Error
>
> (1.4.5) $\left| E \right| \leq 5 \times 10^{r - n}$ where $N = N^* \times 10^r$ (N is expressed in scientific notation)
>
> (1.5.2) $\left| E(f(\overline{N}) \right| \leq \left| f'(\eta) \right|_{\text{max}} \left| E(\overline{N}) \right|$ where $\overline{N}$ approximates $N$ and $\eta$ is between $N$ and $\overline{N}$